# php find the last bracket in string and insert a text before it

Tags: php, mysql

Can someone help me?

I have a program with simple queries and sub ​​queries. within the subqueries I would like to modify the where and the limit. How can I find the last ")" in the query and place "limit 10" before it.

example of a subquery as it can get in the program.

I do have "$Qstring = array_pop(explode(')',$Qstring)); "

```
 SELECT 
    QE.Maand,
    QE.Week,
    QE.`Opzegging direct`,
    QE.`Opzegging einddatum`,
    QE.Totaal,
    QE.`Nieuwe Leverancier`
    FROM
    ( select
    MONTHNAME(calldate) as Maand,
    WEEKOFYEAR(calldate) as Week,
    O1.description as "Omschrijving", 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN O1.description ="Opzegging per direct" THEN 1 END)        AS "Opzegging direct",    
    COUNT(CASE WHEN O1.description ="Opzegging per einddatum" THEN 1 END)        AS "Opzegging einddatum",  
    COUNT(CASE WHEN O1.description ="Opzegging per einddatum" OR O1.description ="Opzegging per direct" THEN 1 END) as Totaal,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN O1.description ="Behouden" THEN 1 END)        AS "Behouden",
    O2.description as "Nieuwe Leverancier" 

    FROM best.prj_004_table LEFT OUTER JOIN best.prj_004_options O1 ON best.prj_004_table.rs_retentieresult = O1.value
    LEFT OUTER JOIN best.prj_004_options O2 ON best.prj_004_table.rs_newsuplier = O2.value 

     O2.description is not NULL  AND year(calldate) = year(CURDATE()) AND MONTH(calldate) = MONTH(CURDATE())    GROUP BY O2.description ORDER BY WEEK(calldate)  ) QE
```

Comment: Your PHP code is suspiciously similar to SQL. Are you sure it's PHP?

Comment: Ofcourse it's PHP! Can you not see the brackets open ( and close ) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM (SELECT col1, col2 FROM table JOIN table2 ON col3=col4)';
$limit = ' LIMIT 5';
$position = strripos($sql ')');
$end = substr($sql, $position);
$replace = substr_replace($sql, $limit, $position);
$replace .= $end;
```

A bit verbose on purpose, but it does the job.